# OData Expand across multiple datasource

Tags: odata, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have created a few Lightswitch HTML apps. Each app has an ApplicationData data source;however, in addition they relate to each other via one or more OData data sources.

For example:

A HumanResource app contains

- Employees table in it's ApplicationData.

A Project Management App contains:

- a Tasks table and a Projects table in it's ApplicationData datasource
- a Employees table in a related OData datasource (HumanResourcesData) which loads data from the Employees table in the HumanResouce app's ApplicationData datasource.

A Task has an Employee related to it as 1..0 or 1

**The problem is**

`myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Tasks.expand("Project, Employees").execute());`

**DOES NOT WORK** which is very understandable.

Tasks can be loaded because they reside in "ApplicationData", Employees cannot because it resides in "HumanResourceData". OData cannot fetch data from 2 sources and magically relate them, and neither can Lightswitch apparently, at least when your manually loading data.

Two solution I can think of are:

1. use `task.getEmployees().then(function(results){});`
   This will cause a roundtrip to the server for every task. **NOT GOOD ENOUGH**
2. `myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Tasks.load()` 
   `myapp.activeDataWorkspace.HumanResourceData.Employees.load()`

   **`//The mystery method that I'm looking for`**
   `Resolve_My_Datas_Relationships_Please_Lightswitch();`

While reviewing trace.axd I noticed that when I drag and drop the collection into the viewmodel and have all the data loaded automagically with related entities and all, I get one call to the HumanResourcesData datasource for each related entity, which looks exactly like solution #1.

This leads me to believe that solution #2 does not exist since it is not the approach that the LightSwitch Team has taken, for which they may have valid reasons (probably because it's very hard to optimize for any particular set of queries if you do not know what they are before hand)

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Have you figured out a way to make this work?  My approach would simply be to merge the applications and use database & role based security to segment different user roles.  Then you're talking to a single datasource and have none of the external data access issues you've described.  

Check out [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9d30b5ef-5251-4193-88bc-df8588d5f608/how-to-run-multiple-screen-query-using-promise-in-lightswitch-html-client?forum=lightswitch), which refers to using lazy loading via promises, then merging the record-sets using a join operation.

Comment: At the moment I keep things segmented, because I am taking a modular approach such as suggested by a service oriented architecture. I took approach number 2, and did it the old fashioned way, by filtering the collection and extracting what I needed.

Comment: The thing I'd say in response is that SOA doesn't necessarily mandate segmentation of data sources at the storage level - just of the services that those data sources provide.  You could quite happily have an Employee service, a Sales service, etc... each with its own data sources, and all with relationships defined in the LightSwitch server-side model - but quite happily have them all persisted in the same database.

However, I'm assuming your response means that it's working as needed, so that's the important thing.  Good luck with it and I hope it gives you what you need!

Comment: Yes it does, I'm a lone developer so it helps me to keep projects segmented. I find it far too problematic to develop monolithic software. Even though each approach does have it's pros/cons, I find the work is easier to define and accomplish with my segmented approach. Lightswitch does not allow multiple html/server clients per project, which I would have liked really, and I image had that been the case, it would have been much easier for them to link up everything. Who knows maybe in the future right?